# Два исключения - это много?

Tags: c++, исключения, деструктор

Вычитал у Майерса, то что два исключения в деструкторе - это слишком много.
Что он этим хотел сказать? Одно исключение - это не много, а вот два - это уже много?
Мне кажется, что уже одно исключение не даст приложению нормально работать?

Comment: А вы уже попробовали?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы его неверно прочли :)

В деструкторе **вообще не должно быть исключений**. Потому что представьте себе - где-то в коде сгенерировано исключение, пошла свертка стека, удаление объектов - т.е. вызовы деструкторов. И если при этом какой-то деструктор сгенерирует исключение - что будет? Будет **два** исключения, причем второе сгенерировано во время обработки первого. Вот что имеется в виду, когда говорится о двух исключениях.

На у а дальше... что же делать дальше? Какое из исключений обрабатывать? Продолжать обработку первого, игнорируя второе? Игнорировать первое и обрабатывать второе?

В результате в этой ситуации программа просто аварийно завершается...